How do I ping an Ip address using scapy and Python?
In my Python homework I need to ping an Ip address 3 times using scapy, I managed to get an Ip address but I don't know how to ping that address. Any suggestions?
I tried Looking online and I found nothing.
this is my code so far to get the Ip of the address the user enters:
second_domain_name = input("Insert domain name: ")
full_msg2 = Ether() / IP(dst=second_domain_name) / ICMP()
ans = srp1(full_msg1, verbose=0)
ip2 = ans[IP].src


If this is homework, that implies an instructor. Didn't they teach how to send the ping before assigning the work?
